# Quoted string escape in SOQL Query

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to query Products in my controller where the Product Name involves min2 to max4 's(apostrophe s) i.e Product Name = Joy's x & Joy's Y & Joy's Z. I am unable to query this product as apostrophe s is hit, it neglects other characters and throws an error like unexpected token s in query.

As per an article to escape quoted string in query
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm

I tried my SOQL query as 
 lstproduct = selectstmt + wherecondition;

In wherecondition = ' Product_Name__r.BrandName__c= \'' + brandstring + '\'';

brandstring holds the product name

> brandstring = ' Joy's x & Joy's Y & Joy's Z ' -----> Here is the
>   issue, on hitting the first apostrophe query ends and nothing is
>   returned in query result.

Please help me resolve this issue. How to change the query to get expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Create some data

```
 list<contact> con = [select id, department from contact limit 20];
    for (contact c : con){
        c.department = ' Joy\'s x & Joy\'s Y & Joy\'s';
    }
    update con;
```

Collect Id's of all contacts that has min2 to max4 of 's and then prepare your soql based on the retrieved id list.

```
list<contact> c = [select id, department from contact];

list<id> i = new list<id>();
for (contact r  : c){
    string[] s = r.department.replace(' ','').split('\'s');
    if(s.size() > 1 && s.size() < 5){
        i.add(r.id);
    }
}
integer a = [select count() from contact where id in :i];
list<contact> a1 = [SELECT Department FROM Contact WHERE Department = 'Joy\'s x & Joy\'s Y & Joy\'s'];
system.assertEquals(a, a1.size());
```